# how to count the number of wget requests?

Tags: php, wget

Is there a way to count how many times a linux administrator performs a `wget` to a number of my files?

or would I have to produce a special `.sh` script to connect to a db and manually update a database record?

Comment: A few questions: Does your webserver collect access logs? Is the administrator on the same server?

Comment: are they running wget from bash on the same machine?

Comment: Just for an example, the administrator is performing the wget to my server from another server located x amount of miles away from where mine is hosted.

Comment: Apache access logs, the user agent with be "*wget*" unless changed by the admin

Comment: there is no fool-proof way to accomplish this unless you know the ip running the wget

Comment: Thats rather disapointing